# Unable to emit to Node server using Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, google-chrome, websocket

I'm using socket.io in my project and was having trouble emiting data to the server, so I set up a simple test case. I've created a file, `index.html` which I've opened in Google Chrome (using a file:// address):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
            socket.emit('clientDetails', {hello: 'world'});

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('clientDetails', {hello: 'world'});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

And I have this verys imple code on my Node server:

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

// Make the server listen on porr 8080
app.listen(8080);

io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log("Client connected");
});

io.on('clientDetails', function(socket) {
    console.log("Got client details");
});
```

When I load up the HTML page in Chrome, I get a `Client connected` message printed by Node. All is good. But I never see a `Got client details` string.

I suspect there is something wrong with the server as looking in Chrome's network tools I can see the data being sent to the server, at least I think that's what this is:

[image]

Why am I not able to capture the client sending data to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-node-http-server), the following:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log("Client connected");
});

io.on('clientDetails', function(socket) {
    console.log("Got client details");
});
```

Should be

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log("Client connected");

    socket.on('clientDetails', function(data) {
        console.log("Got client details");
    });
});
```